# Cannot Update / Add fields on an object in parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm having a problem updating an object field with a key and a value on the user instance. The code runs successfully by saving but does not update the key on the object. Here is the code that I'm running

```
let query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

app.post("/saveListName", function (req, res) {

 query.get(req.body.userObjectId, {
            success: function (user) {
                console.log(user);

                user.set("list.foo", "Hello world"); //this is what I'm updating

                user.save(null, {
                    useMasterKey: true
                }).then(function (res) {
                    console.log("User saved");
                    console.log(res);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                })
                res.send(true);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send(false);
            }
        })
})
```

**foo** is the key I'm trying to update on the **list** object. And I want to dynamically add new keys to the list object but not only one key. Please, I need help with this. I'm wondering if this feature(dynamically appending/removing fields on an object) is even supported in parse because going through documentation http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#updating-objects and I have not seen anything like that. Thanks